# Unable to uninstall or find any details about iTunes but still i am able see logo in Applications

Tags: package-management, .desktop, itunes

I am sure, I've uninstalled iTunes but don't know how logo is displaying in applications.

[image: itunes in my Applications]

I tried to view all the list file using `sudo apt list` but nothing regarding iTunes and also searched in packages to find iTunes and manually remove but it's not helpful, I want to remove it but unable to find a solution.

Comment: What is the output of `grep -r "iTunes" ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications`?

Comment: Thanks kulfy, this command helped me with the problem and i successfully removed the file associations with wine and able to remove wine 

 https://appuals.com/unregister-wine-file-associations-linux/   --- this blog documentation is good and using this I am able to remove wine

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would have installed iTunes using `apt`, since it is not open source and would not be in the Ubuntu repositories.

Almost all instructions I can find for how to install iTunes in Linux say to use `wine` and the Windows installer.

Have you tried running `wine uninstaller` from the terminal?

Comment: Yes  I tried wine uninstaller but no use

Answer (score 0):

Using this command, I am able to find `wine` file allocations

```
grep -r "iTunes" ~/.local/share/applications /usr/share/applications
```

Go to this link and you will able to remove all the file allocations  https://appuals.com/unregister-wine-file-associations-linux/

Once you removed the file allocations type below command, it will attempt to remove all packages starting with wine. Pay attention and check that the package list does not include any packages you want to keep before you select yes.

```
sudo apt remove ^wine
```

#### Search package lists for relevant things

```
dpkg --list | grep wine
```

This will give you a list of packages installed whose names contain the string `wine`. You can manually copy the package names you want to uninstall and use `sudo apt remove` command.